# Google Maps app and multiple Google accounts, only signing in for one account possible?

Tags: google-maps

I link several Google accounts on my phone. The Google Maps app usually shows notifications associated with my first account, but my Google maps account which I use the most is one of the others.

The app allows signing out an account (from the 3-minus menu, Settings, Sign out of Google Maps). But then after a while or after a reboot, all accounts would be signed in automatically again.

Is there a way to make sign out permanent? Or a way to only show notifications for certain account only (the Notifications settings apply to all accounts).

Comment: Try updating your maps and see if that helps

Comment: @beeshyams Did that yesterday, nope didn't help. Accounts always gets signed in again, and the notification settings is global, not per account. I guess I'm out of luck.

Comment: @hepi-mott did you file a bug report/feature request with google that we can add to?

Comment: @SampsonCrowley no i didn't.